# Best way of defining a non-file output of a task and using it in another task in Gradle

Tags: gradle

Assume I have a task flow like this:
[image]

Task B and C depend on Task A.
Now, say I want to use the value "dogs" in the tasks:
[image]

What would be the best way of doing that? Gradle allows doing this using @OutputFile:

```
    @OutputFile
    File outputFile;
```

But there is no equivalent @Output for non-files:

```
    @Output
    int dogs;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tasks Outputs**

There is no in memory value sharing between task that would be taken into consideration for incremental builds. While its still valid option to write this value of `dogs=16` into file and then read the value from the file in other tasks.

**Sharing properties**

Alternative approach is that your task A defines [extra property](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#sec:extra_properties) on Project object (or other objects if needed), e.g. `project.extra["dogs"]=16`. After that task B and C can read from the same property, `val shepherdDogs = project.extra["dogs"]`. While of course if task doesn't have outputs the task would be executed with each build; you won't be able to utilize [incremental builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/incremental_build.html#incremental_build). It has to be executed always as this property is stored in memory and each time you run build you'll have to set value for the dogs as the value isn't stored somewhere in the file.